# postLoad execute UPDATE instead of updating Entity state

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have **Entity Menu** that has a collection of **Page Entities**.
Page entity has a **postLoad** event which is setting **Image field** to a **Symfony** compatible format.

Whenever I **update Menu Entity** it will also **trigger UPDATE for Image field** to **DB for all Collection related Page** entities, but It should just **mutate** Entity object how familiar I am with Doctrine Event listeners.

This is also related to: **https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4507**

Comment: Can you post your code of the Page Entities and Menu Entity please?

Comment: You are in Symfony also ? Because it is It's tightly linked to the same, 
but the problem is related to Doctrine.

Comment: If you do not share more information on what the Post Load does and how the doctrines entites are configured I can't help. Sorry